# Perl not continuing

Tags: perl

Note: This is a test perl code to check if works.

I have problem with my perl script, I know there's a solution for that by adding

```
print "Your server is not ok, please check!\n";
die "- Server is not ok!\n";
```

But in my project after stop in `die "- Server is not ok!\n";` continue the script, I use print to show if works.

Heres the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => 1 );
$ua->agent("007");

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => 'http://www.google.com.ph/' );

my $res;
for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    $res = $ua->request($req);
    if ( $res->is_success ) {
        print "+ Server is ok!\n";
    }
    else {
        die "- Server is not ok!\n"; # I want to stop if server is not ok and print last code. Or other solution to stop instead of using die.
    }
    sleep 1;
}
print "Your server is not ok, please check!\n"; # Why this print not showing if stop in "- Server is not ok!\n"?
```

See image...

[image]

Other solution to stop? Intead using `die` to continue the perl script.

I hope someone will fixed this little problem, thanks for all reply!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The output seems correct. `die` terminates the program, not the loop. What's the problem?

Comment: Other way to stop `HTTP::Request` and print the last.

Comment: If you want to break out of the loop, use `last;`.

Comment: @minitech Where do I put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    $res = $ua->request($req);
    if ( $res->is_success ) {
        print "+ Server is ok!\n";
    }
    else {
       print "- Server is not ok!\n"; 
       last; #this statement causes to exit the loop
    }
    sleep 1;
}

# at this point everything is oke
print "Your server is ok!\n";
```

Comment: I want to stop in `- Server is not ok!\n` and continue or print the last code.

Comment: want to continue with the for loop?

Comment: so you want to make a loop checks all servers and stop if a server is not oke.. and dont check other servers?

Comment: Thank you to your wonderful answer, my perl script is now working flawlessly.

Comment: I have another problem, check this http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=14gfmz3N. I think you can fix this.

Comment: introduce a extra paramers : serversAllGood  and on the else block set serversAllGood to false. when you are out of the loop you can check if serversAllGood   is true or false

Comment: I think this'd benefit from an actual explanation, rather than just a code block.